# How to restrict passwordless SSH?

Tags: ssh

SSH allows user to create keys that do not have a password. That goes against some security requirements.

How to implement a policy in OpenSSH where SSH keys without a passphrase will not work?

Is `PermitEmptyPasswords` only applied to logins without a key? Or to all password prompts in a generic way?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but another option may be to configure [`PubKeyAuthOptions`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config.5#PubkeyAuthOptions). I haven't used it because my keys are one firmware revision behind the required revision to support it.

Comment: @Paul, this option is related to FIDO, Two-Factor Authentication (2FA), not about the key encryption.

Comment: Your security requirements is broken

Comment: What are the ACTUAL security requirements?  Please be very specific.

Answer (score 30):

To address what appears to be a fundamental misunderstanding in the question:

When you create a key, the difference between having a passphrase for the key or not is whether that key is stored encrypted (protected by that passphrase) or in the plain in the key file that is created.

Ie, the prompting for a passphrase is entirely a client behavior, necessary to read the key on the client side, not a behavior that involves the server side.

If you want to ensure keys are stored encrypted, that is a client-side thing to try to enforce.
Alternatively you may want to require some other authentication method altogether, or multiple authentication methods.

Comment: A useful analogy might be users writing down their password on a piece of paper taped to their monitor - you can have a policy that says they must not do that, but you cannot configure an SSH server to reject logins from users who do it. The server can check if the user gives the correct password, but has no idea if they typed it from memory, copied it from a well-secured password manager, or read it from a piece of paper. In the same way, it can check if they provided the correct key, but cannot tell what format it was stored in, and what if any password was used to encrypt it at rest.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot enforce a passphrase on a key. However, to enforce two-factor authentication (something you have, the key, and something you know, the password) you can use another option.

In OpenSSH you can set the `AuthenticationMethods publickey,password` parameter in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. This will force the user to use both public key AND password authentication, effectively giving you two-factor authentication.

Comment: But there's still no way to prevent the user from storing the password in a file and feeding it to ssh instead of typing it in.

Comment: @TooTea Ultimately, you cannot protect users from themselves. Some amount of training and accountability is always required.

Answer (score 7):

The option you mention is valid for password, not keys. If you want to have strict policies about the keys I see two options:

1. Do security scan of users workstations and check if the keys are encrypted.
2. Implement something like key management system where the users should create the keys and on servers the keys are provided via this KMS and not stored locally. Using this way you can be sure the private keys are encrypted.

Comment: Option 2 won't work: once the key is out of the KMS, the client can do whatever it pleases with it. (Also, the users would need to authenticate themselves to the KMS, which makes the original problem reappear in a slightly different form.)

Comment: @bass, no, the key is extracted every time, check `AuthorizedKeysCommand`

Comment: You must have envisioned some clever way of distributing keys that I can only guess at, or then I'm misinterpreting what part of the comment your "no" is denying. However, it's unavoidable that at some point, the client must have access to the unencrypted secret key, else it won't be able to authenticate itself. At that point, there is no server-side way to prevent the client from storing the secret key wherever, in whichever form the client chooses.

Comment: @bass, I get your point. And yes, in most cases 2 wont work well. :)

Answer (score 4):

`PermitEmptyPasswords` does not apply to key based authentication, it specifies if a login without a password is allowed.

The server does not know if the client had to use a password to unlock the key or not. There is no way to restrict this from the server side.